# How do you configure WorkManagers in WebLogic 10.3?

Tags: concurrency, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I would like to use a WorkManager to schedule some parallel jobs on a WebLogic 10.3 app server.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/resource/spi/work/WorkManager.html

I'm finding the Oracle/BEA documentation a bit fragmented and hard to follow and it does not have good examples for using WorkManagers from EJB 3.0.

Specifically, I'd like to know:

1) What exactly, if anything, do I need to put in my deployment descriptors (ejb-jar.xml and friends)?

2) I'd like to use the @Resource annotation to inject the WorkManager into my EJB 3 session bean.  What "name" do I use for the resource?

3) How do I configure the number of threads and other parameters for the WorkManager.

My understanding is that the underlying implementation on WebLogic is CommonJ, but I'd prefer to use a non-proprietary approach if possible.

Comment: I ended up abandoning Work Managers in favour of the approach using TimerService that is described in this article.

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/33694/1954

Simpler and more portable and a better fit for the simple requirements that I had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you'll find the documentation of CommonJ, an implementation of the Timer and Work Manager API developed by <strike>BEA</strike> Oracle and IBM, in [Timer and Work Manager API (CommonJ) Programmer’s Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/commonj/commonj.html). They provide a Work Manager Example but it's not injected in this document.

> 1) What exactly, if anything, do I need to put in my deployment descriptors (ejb-jar.xml and friends)?

According to the [Work Manager Deployment](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/commonj/commonj.html#wp1058134) section:

> Work Managers are defined at the
>   server level via a resource-ref in the
>   appropriate deployment descriptor.
>   This can be web.xml or ejb-jar.xml
>   among others.
>
> The following deployment descriptor
>   fragment demonstrates how to configure
>   a `WorkManager`:
>
> ```
> ...
> <resource-ref>
>    <res-ref-name>wm/MyWorkManager</res-ref-name>
>    <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
>    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
> </resource-ref>
> ...
> ```
>
> **Note:** The recommended prefix for the JNDI namespace for WorkManager
>   objects is java:comp/env/wm.

Check the [WorkManager](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/commonj/work/WorkManager.html) javadocs for more details (e.g. "*The res-auth and res-sharing scopes are ignored in this version of the specification. The EJB or servlet can then use the WorkManager as it needs to.*").

> 2) I'd like to use the @Resource annotation to inject the WorkManager into my EJB 3 session bean. What "name" do I use for the resource?

I'd say something like this (not tested):

```
@ResourceRef(jndiName="java:comp/env/wm/MyWorkManager",
auth=ResourceRef.Auth.CONTAINER,
type="commonj.work.WorkManager",
name="MyWorkManager")
```

> 3) How do I configure the number of threads and other parameters for the WorkManager.

See the description of the [`<work-manager>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/programming/app_xml.html#wp1075208) element and [Using Work Managers to Optimize Scheduled Work](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_wls/self_tuned.html) for detailed information on Work Managers

> My understanding is that the underlying implementation on WebLogic is CommonJ, but I'd prefer to use a non-proprietary approach if possible.

I don't have any other suggestion (and, as long as this implementation follows the standards, I wouldn't mind using it).

Comment: It looks like 1) and 2) are two different versions of the same thing?  I'm assuming you only need to do 2) is a pure EJB 3 app?

Comment: I think so too. But I did test 1), not 2)

Answer (score 0):

The Weblogic documentation will answer your questions.
[Using Work Managers to Optimize Scheduled Work](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24432/self_tuned.htm#CNFGD112)